# vim - What's the best way to set statusline color to change, based on mode

Tags: vim, colors, gvimrc, statusbar

I've tried to improve my vim experience trying to have the vim statusline color to change everytime the mode changes.

I've triend this: 
(found [here](https://gabri.me/blog/diy-vim-statusline/))

```
    "Automatically change the statusline color depending on mode
function! ChangeStatuslineColor()
  if (mode() =~# '\v(n|no)')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=008'
  elseif (mode() =~# '\v(v|V)' || g:currentmode[mode()] ==# 'V·Block' || get(g:currentmode, mode(), '') ==# 't')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=005'
  elseif (mode() ==# 'i')
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=004'
  else
    exe 'hi! StatusLine ctermfg=006'
  endif

  return ''
endfunction
```

...and include:

```
set statusline+=%{ChangeStatuslineColor()}
```

But there's an issue, if you switch to `insert` mode and then press `Esc` to come back to `normal` mode, it doesn't change back the color. It'll change back the color only when you manually enter a different mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically modifying the `StatusLine` highlight group is the wrong approach. This overrides any presets of your *colorscheme*, and it doesn't seem to work (maybe the addition of a `:redraw[status]` would help, but that would make it an even uglier implementation).

Vim allows to specify a custom highlight group in the statusline (even multiple), with the `%#HLname#` symbol. See `:help 'statusline'` for details. You can either dynamically change the `'statusline'` value (this also allows different colors for different statuslines), or use the `%!MyStatusLine()` approach that re-evaluates the value itself.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Seems to be a better solution indeed. I'll get my head on it, thanks